# Validating data with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, validation

I have read a csv into DataFrame. CSV contains the following records

```
name,address,stars,contact,phone,uri
```

I want to apply validators base on these following rules

1. Name should be UTF-8 String
2. URI Should be a valid URL
3. Stars should be a digit from 0 to 5

The validated data would go into a json file.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish your validations?

Comment: Not yet @harvpan, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the Pandas documentation, found the way to validate the data.

Let's just say you have a custom validation function.

```
def validate_rating(rating):
    """"
    Description:
        validate if hotel rating is a digit between 0 to 5

    Args:
        rating (str): rating to be validated

    Returns:
        True if rating is valid
        False if rating is not a valid
    """

    try:
        rating = int(rating)
        if rating < 0 or rating > 5:
            return False
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Once you've read the CSV into dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df['stars'].apply(validate_rating)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.astype(dtype={"column_name1":"dtype1", "column_name2":"dtype2", …})
```

The above will return an error if any columns cannot be converted into your desired `dtype`.